# Don't have Run As -> Scala Test in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, unit-testing

I recently re-installed my OS from scratch (Debian). Then did following:

- Installed Scala from the repository
- Installed Eclipse Kepler from the repository
- Installed Scala IDE from inside Eclipse
- created a Scala class
- created a Scala test which makes a new instance of my class
- copied the scalatest jar into the project and added it to the build path

Here, I noticed that I don't have "Run as -> Scala test" in the menu. Looked at the versions and noticed that I have installed a Scala IDE which is made for Scala 2.10, but I have 2.10 installed. The Eclipse version 3.8 was correct.

So I uninstalled the repository scala, downloaded 2.10.4 and installed it manually, setting both $SCALA_HOME and $PATH. I restarted the computer in case Eclipse has loaded some dependencies to the old scala, and tried running the test again. But to no avail; I have the choice to run a scala application, but not a scala test.

[image: my run configurations window]

My mini-test is extremely simple and doesn't reference anything unusual:

```
import org.scalatest._
import Matchers._

class StudySpec extends FlatSpec {
  "It" should "be possible to create a new Study with the default constructor." in {
    val newStudy = new Study()
  }
```

What did I do wrong, and how can I get the test to run?

Comment: `http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse` according to doc, you will need a [plugin](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: @jilen thank you! I was at least three times at that page, but somehow I got confused, thinking that installing the Scala IDE from the url they cite will automatically contain the plugin. I had looked at the entries in the installation window, but upon seeing "incubation" behind the plugins thought that they are just some new, unstable versions. If you write this as an answer, with the explanation what exactly to install (the doc seems to be too terse for Eclipse noobs like me), you'll get an easy +25 from me.

Comment: Have you install the `ScalaTest for Scala IDE` component at the section `Scala IDE plugins(incubation)` ? I install both scala-ide and scalatest for scala ide and is fine!

Comment: @jilen I hadn't, but after reading your first comment, I did, and it worked. So if you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't Install the `ScalaTest plugin for Scala IDE`. Just install it.